# Multiple File batch variable is offset

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, var, lf

So I am trying to write a script to check remote machines to see if they have specific updates.
It works when there is 1 entry in variable. However, It would be much better if I could check multiple variables and return a result for each variable.
for example: a=x , b=y, c=w     check for x & print result; check for y & print, check for w & print.
also, don't know why but it seems to offset every variable name by 1 20h2=0h2, except derp.

```
set "20h2=KB4562830"
set "1809=KB1234567"
set "20H2-SEC=KB2456789"
set "DERP=Four"

set ^"RECENTS=%20h2%^

%1809%^

%20h2-sec%^

%DERP%^"



echo ++Looking for !RECENTS!

psexec -accepteula \\%COMPUTER% cmd /c powershell.exe -command "& {get-hotfix -computername localhost  | select InstalledOn,HotFixID,Description | Sort-Object -Descending -Property InstalledOn -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |findstr !RECENTS!}
""
```

Comment: And don't start a variable name with a number. `%20h2%` is interpreted as "the value of the second parameter" (`%2`, probably empty) followed by the literal string `0h2`. The closing `%` is ignored (considered as an opening `%` but invalidated because there is no matching closing `%`)

Comment: @Stephan, I am on my phone and cannot test. But does the `^` after `set` not cause an error?

Comment: (although I guess `findstr` can't handle the multi-line variable properly)

Comment: @Stephan, `findstr` *can* search beyond line-breaks but they have to literally equal, hence carriage-return plus line-feed characters must be specified; but the whole multi-line string is then considered as a *single* search expression, so this is not suitable to find one out of a (multi-line) list; note that `findstr` just returns the first line of the match. The asker would need `findstr /G` here…

Comment: @aschipfl I know it can search over multiline. But what about the "linefeeds" in the searchstring?

Comment: @Stephan, the won't match anything, assuming the command line left of the pipe outputs standard Windows line-breaks (CR + LF)…

Comment: @Stephan  ok thank you I didn't know it would do that, I'll just work around with another name then.

Comment: @aschipfl  is there an argument that would be better fitted to assembly line like input?  Or is there a way to structure a command so that it loops to check through multiple arguments?    I would like it to check for and print all of the arguments.

Comment: `for %%a in (alpha beta gamma delta) do echo %%a`

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, that worked.